# Calling controller method from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to call a controller method from a javascript method. I have the following code:

```
function test() {
        $.ajax({
        url: @Url.Action("abc"),
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(data) { alert(data); }
   });
     }



[HttpGet]
        public string abc(string id)
        {
            return "Info";
        }
```

How is it possible to get the "info" string back, in my alert() in the Javascript controller?

Comment: What error messages are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: There are no errors. Nothing happens..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dataType attribute in ajax call.

Try this one:

```
function test() {
    $.ajax({
      url: @Url.Action("abc"),
      method: 'GET',
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data) { alert(data); }
   });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. i had to change some Chrome settings.